# No (se) puede quedar, No (se) va a quedar(Perífrasis verbal)(Verbo pronominal)(Pronombre reflexivo átono)

Tags: verbo-pronominal

Estaba viendo ayer un canal de deportes y en el GC apareció *"Zárate **se** termina yéndo**se** por la ventana. Juan Pablo Marrón."* (Me suena repetitivo)

- Zárate **se** termina yendo por la ventana.
- Zárate termina yéndo**se** por la ventana

Ambas como algo que se está tramitando, es decir el contrato todavía no termina, termina a fin de año, pero existe una cláusula de salida en junio, como p.ej en prostituyéndose, es decir la persona está 'prostituting herself/himself' o 'being a prostitute', posiblemente indica que es algo que está en proceso.

También, esa frase me hizo pensar en éstas(que me suenan intercambiables con y sin 'se'):

- Esto no puede quedar así. (¿Acá debería ser 'quedar**se**'? ¿O eso es más bien coloquial?)
- Esto no **se** puede quedar así.
- Esto no **se** quedará así.
- Esto no **se** va a quedar así.
- Esto no va a quedar**se** así (¿Coloquial?)

El verbo quedarse es pronominal, por lo tanto se construye con un pronombre reflexivo átono, pero en este caso no es 'esto no se queda' sino que una perífrasis verbal 'no se **puede quedar**', 'no se **va a quedar**' funciona de la misma forma? O también se puede decir 'no puede quedar así', 'no va a quedar así' sin el 'se'? Quiero saber ya sea correcta o no, ¿A qué **tiempo verbal** se traduce en inglés?

Intentos:

- It cannot remain as it is.
- This cannot remain as it stands.
- It can't stay that way.
- It won't stay like that.
- This cannot continue.
- This cannot remain the same.

Otros ejemplos:

- **Comida** que **se** descompone y no **se** puede vender.
- Este último **caso** **se** da porque obviamente no **se** pueden superponer dos sonidos iguales.

¿Da lo mismo ocupar el 'se' con un 'it', ej. 'sonido' o 'comida' que con un sujeto como 'he/she' p.ej. Zárate?

---

EDIT:
En base a lo expuesto por Gustavson.

> 3. Quedar para señalar el resultado de una acción o situación (turn out).

It turned out great(=Han quedado bastante bien(ES, SP), quedaron bien){con 'se' se refiere a algo que hicieron}

En los 5 ejemplos que expuso no se usa 'se' para referirse a una persona o cosa, me interesaba ese uso particular, como en:

- ¿Por qué esta canción **se** ha quedado fuera del LP?(=Why this song isn't in the LP)(ES, SP)

En este ejemplo también me suena posible:

- ¿Por qué esta canción ha quedado fuera del LP? sin 'se'.

En mi variedad:

- ¿Por qué esta canción quedó fuera del LP?
- ¿Por qué esta canción **se** quedó fuera del LP?

> 2. Quedarse para señalar un cambio de situación (get)

De acuerdo, acá más ejemplos:

- Se quedó furiosa conmigo(=she gets very angry, she got mad, she was furious)
- Se quedó muy desanimado(=was disappointed, he was pretty despondent, he feels discouraged)
- Se quedaban maravillados de sus dotes(=People were astonished/amazed.. )
- Todo el mundo se quedó feliz(=Everybody was happy)
- Se quedó callado(=He didn't say anything)
- Se me quedó grabado (=I couldn't get that stuff out of my mind, It stuck in my mind)

> 1. Quedarse como sinónimo de permanecer (stay)

En los tres ejemplos no se usa 'se' para referirse a una persona, como en:

- Los nuevos se quedaron(=..stayed) con él por el resto del día.{The new ones stayed the rest of the day.}
- Se quedó hasta el 2014(=He hung on until..)
- Se quedan de brazos cruzados(=stayed)
- Los convencí de que se quedaran.(=I convinced 'em to stick around, ..to stay, ..to remain)

> Se usaría QUEDARSE si "así" indicara por ejemplo una postura corporal
> o reemplazara a un adjetivo:

Concuerdo, acá dos ejemplos:

- Se quedó mirando(=She kept standing there)
- Se quedó de espaldas(=..lay back, ..stays on his/her back)

En el ejemplo de quedarse así me refería p.ej. a alguien que busca cambiar el statu quo.

Esto no se quedará así(=..won't stay like this/that way/this way, =..won't stand for, ..can't allow this situation to continue)

> En las oraciones en cuestión, se usa QUEDAR (acepción 3) para indicar
> que el resultado no es el deseado.

Sin embargo en mi variedad creo que 'se' es para otorgarle un matiz coloquial (solamente en ese ejemplo), en algunos me parece literario, formal, en otros creo que se debe anteponer al verbo y no ser añadido al final porque de esa forma parece anticuado p.ej. Había prometídole, pero en otros no, ej. Siempre está quejándose(=is always complaining, de nuevo con -ing)

Acá está explicado en detalle, sin embargo los ejemplos de uso a veces no concuerdan con los enclíticos en relación al verbo.
https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estoy de acuerdo en que:

"Zárate **se** termina yéndo**se** por la ventana"

es incorrecto, por duplicación de "se". Debe ser:

- Zárate **se** termina yendo por la ventana.

o

- Zárate termina yéndo**se** por la ventana.

En ambos casos, el verbo es "irse" (go away).

En cuanto a los verbos "quedar" y "quedarse", tienen distintos usos. He encontrado [esta página](https://hablacultura.com/quedar-y-quedarse/#:%7E:text=En%20el%20caso%20de%20los,su%20forma%20pronominal%20(quedarse).) que los resume bastante bien:

QUEDAR

1. *Quedar* en las citas (fix an appointment, agree to meet)

– ¿Por qué no quedamos?

– ¿A qué hora quedamos?

– ¿Dónde quedamos?

2. *Quedar* como sinónimo de acordar (agree)

– Quedamos en que yo me ocupaba de hacer la comida y tú de lo demás, pero la verdad es que estoy haciendo todo yo.

– ¿En qué quedamos?

3. *Quedar* para señalar el resultado de una acción o situación (turn out).
   En estos casos el verbo *quedar* suele ir acompañado de un adverbio de modo o un adjetivo que señala la cualidad del resultado.

– El trabajo ha quedado genial.

– El libro quedó perfecto.

– Alberto Contador ha quedado agotado en la contrarreloj del sábado.

– Oscar quedó como un imbécil en las cartas que le escribía a Bea.

– Tras las medidas tomadas, el director de la compañía ha quedado muy bien con todos sus empleados.

4. *Quedar* para señalar algo que nos sobra después de haber realizado una acción, o también lo que tenemos aún en un determinado momento del proceso (be left, remain)

– En el estreno de la película quedaron 200 entradas sin vender.

– Me quedan solo 100 euros para terminar el mes.

– El tiempo que le quede libre debería dedicarlo a estudiar.

– No queda nada de agua.

5. *Quedar* en situaciones relacionadas con el tiempo señala el tiempo que falta para llegar a un destino o para que termine una acción (be left, remain)

– Solo quedan dos horas para llegar a Santander.

– Aún quedan 20 minutos para que termine la película.

QUEDARSE – Uso pronominal del verbo quedar

1. *Quedarse* como sinónimo de permanecer (stay)

– En el viaje de vacaciones nos quedamos 10 días en Mallorca.

– Cuando vaya a Barcelona me quedaré en casa de unos amigos.

– Los viernes por la noche siempre me quedo en casa porque estoy muy cansado. Solo salgo los sábados.

2. *Quedarse* para señalar un cambio de situación (get)

– El niño se ha quedado dormido.

– Mi padre se ha quedado delgadísimo.

3. *Quedarse* para expresar que retenemos algo, que no lo damos (keep for oneself, retain)

– Se ha quedado con todos mis libros y no me los quiere devolver.

4. *Quedarse* como sinónimo de adquirir o comprar (keep for oneself)

– Ya me he decidido, me quedo con los pantalones grises.

En las oraciones en cuestión, se usa QUEDAR (acepción 3) para indicar que el resultado no es el deseado:

- Esto no puede quedar así.
- Esto no quedará así.
- Esto no va a quedar así.

Se usaría QUEDARSE si "así" indicara por ejemplo una postura corporal o reemplazara a un adjetivo:

- No puedes quedarte así. Te van a doler los huesos. (You cannot stay like this. Your bones will hurt.)
- No puedes quedarte así. Tienes que decir algo. (You cannot stay like this, i.e. silent. You have to say something.)

Los últimos ejemplos son diferentes:

- Comida que se descompone y no se puede vender. ("descomponerse" necesita "se" para ser intransitivo; "se" en "venderse" tiene valor pasivo) (Food that goes bad and cannot be sold.)
- Este último caso se da porque obviamente no se pueden superponer dos sonidos iguales. ("darse" necesita "se" para ser intransitivo; "se" in "superponerse" tiene valor recíproco o pasivo) (This last case occurs because, obviously, two equal sounds cannot overlap each other / cannot be overlapped.)